# Images to fit container height

Tags: css

I'm using the following code to build a horizontal scrolling gallery. I'd like for the images with a height of more than 600 pixels to fit their container (exhibit-slide). If I use the height property instead of the max-height in the img tag it works, but then the gallery layout stops being responsive to resizing.

```
<div id="exhibit-slides">
    <div class="exhibit-slide">
    <img src="http://01.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="exhibit-slide">
    <img src="http://02.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="exhibit-slide">
    <img src="http://03.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="exhibit-slide">
    <img src="http://04.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

#exhibit-slides {
    overflow:auto; 
    width:10000px;
}

.exhibit-slide {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    max-height:600px;
}

img {
    width:auto;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`.exhibit-slide {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    height:600px;
    **overflow-y:hidden**
}`

Comment: I tried this and the images are not responsive to window resizing